# How does Android handle multiple substitution in translation text?

Tags: android, translation, message

I need to enter text like the following

> So far {0, integer} items added out of {1, integer} items.

It does not do the substitution. Here is my code which should do the substitution.

```
MyActivity.this.getString(R.string.msgSoFarOutOf, new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(itemsAdded), Integer.valueOf(itemssTotal)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `%d`, `%s`, etc., same as for `String.format()`. BTW, [getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is a varargs method, so you don't need an array.

Comment: Code compiler in Eclipse complains when more than one %s is used.

Comment: It might benefit you to actually read the message, and maybe search in Google. Or at the very least, post the actual message here. 'Complains' doesn't really mean much. BTW, you need to specify the positions explicitly: `$1%s $2%s $3%s` to get this to work.